# Getting a list index out of range and i'm not sure why

Tags: python, django

I get a index list out of range error and cant figure out why. The error seems to be occurring at the line **p2 = 'FLipkart Price: $' +  price2[0].text**. For some reason the similar code that pertains to the the variable **p** works fine but not this one. If it helps, I am just trying to make a website that compares prices at amazon and flipkit. I am using python and the Django framework.

```
def search_item(request):
item = ''
if request.method == 'POST':
    item = request.POST.get('textfield')

    wbd = wb.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
    #webdriver_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
    amazon_url = 'https://www.amazon.com/'
    flip_url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/'
    
    search_url = amazon_url + ("s?k=%s" % (item))
    print(search_url)
    wbd.get(search_url)
    price = wbd.find_elements_by_class_name('a-price-whole')
    p = 'Amazon Price: $' + price[0].text
    l = 'Link: ' + search_url
    
    search_url2 = flip_url + ("search?q=%s" % (item))
    print(search_url2)
    wbd.get(search_url2)
    price2 = wbd.find_elements_by_class_name('_1vC4OE')
    p2 = 'FLipkart Price: $' +  price2[0].text
    l2 = "Flipkart Link: " + search_url2
    
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'aprice': p, 'alink': l, 'fprice': p2, 'flink': l2})
```

Comment: When I fetch that FlipKart page, there are no elements with class name "_1vC4OE".  It is possible they are generating those class names on the fly to prevent what you are attempting to do.

Comment: show your output logs. but if you're getting an out of range error, it means that you're trying to index an element which does not exist, so `price2` is empty. Read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to learn how to debug and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a better question next time, so that folk are more willing to help you. Let me know if you need help with the debugging, but I would recommend using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to inspect the contents of `price` and `price2`, or just print them

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code?

Comment: @TimRoberts I believe that was the issue. They do generate new ones and I neglected to check. Thanks!